# How to remove button Add New Category (editor-post-taxonomies) in post editor

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

[image: Add New Category - how to remove this link?]

**Add New Category** - how to remove this link?

When creating a taxonomy, I use the `default_term` argument, so I no longer need the functionality to create and edit taxonomies, I only need the ability to select from those taxonomies that I created using `default_term`.

Removed from the menu - `show_in_menu` set to **false**. But I don't understand how to remove this link when creating a taxonomy?

Help remove the ability to edit in the post editor.

Comment: You can't do it from PHP change. Maybe you can hide it with CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The following CSS selector can be used to target and hide the *"Add New Category"* button:

```css
.components-button.editor-post-taxonomies__hierarchical-terms-add{
    display: none;
}
```

It's also possible to create your own [Custom Taxonomy Selector](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/tree/a71352ea2eaad71af5de551b343fc6aa65e049b6/packages/editor/src/components/post-taxonomies#posttaxonomies) component to replace the existing UI using JavaScript; as you need only to hide the button, I would use CSS in this case.